# Converting file from python to exe

Tags: python, csv, exe

I've written a file that converts the delimiter in a CSV from format ',' to the ';'.
I'm trying to convert this file from a .py to a .exe using auto-py-to-exe. Whilst this process does work and execute correctly clicking on the app does not do anything.

Am I missing something from the code? Perhaps an auto execute command?

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
  
  
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  
  
# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
      
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',')
    df.to_csv(f, sep=';', index = False)
```

Comment: How do you run this? Are there any .csv files in the same directory? To debug, print the file names. Or does your program finish so quickly that it looks like nothing is happening? Please [edit] your question and add these details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `argparse` to provide the inpu# import necessary libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import argparse
  
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Adding optional argument
parser.add_argument("-i", "--InputPath", help="Input path files")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--OutPath", help="Out path files")


path = os.path.abspath(args.InputPath)
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  
  
# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
      
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',')
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(args.OutPath),f), sep=';', index = False)
```

Then simply use the `auto-py-to-exe` to generate the exe.

Open the `cmd` to the place where the exe is there and use it accordingly.

CMD: 
`$ file.py -i "input path" -o "Out path"`